# Windows 10 not connecting properly with Samba 4.7.6 on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: samba, windows-10, file-sharing

Before upgrading my main server to Ubuntu 18.04 LTS I decided to test the installation first on a spare laptop. All went well until I wanted to browse for files in Windows Explorer via Samba.

My Windows 10 machine can browse files (via Samba) on my main Ubuntu server (version Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS running Samba version 4.3.11-Ubuntu). However it cannot browse files on the Ubuntu 18.04 server running Samba version 4.7.6-Ubuntu. The Windows 10 machine can see the Ubuntu 18.04 server in windows explorer but every time I click to access the 'shared' folders and files I get a message saying windows cannot access the server.

I have googled for hours and tried various possible solutions proposed by others but can't get anything to work. I can access the shared areas on either Ubuntu machine from the other machine using smbclient. I take this to mean my smb.conf file is largely correct.

Can anyone please shed some light onto this problem and what the solution might be. Thanks.

To simplify matters I currently have the smb.conf files the same on both Ubuntu servers. As explained above Windows 10 can access the files on one server but not on the other.

```
smb.conf

[global]
        server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
        server role = standalone server
        security = USER
        map to guest = Bad User
        obey pam restrictions = Yes
        pam password change = Yes
        passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
        passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
        username map = /etc/samba/smbusers
        unix password sync = Yes
        syslog = 0
        log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
        max log size = 1000
        dns proxy = No
        usershare allow guests = Yes
        panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
        idmap config * : backend = tdb


[printers]
        comment = All Printers
        path = /var/spool/samba
        create mask = 0700
        printable = Yes
        browseable = No


[print$]
        comment = Printer Drivers
        path = /var/lib/samba/printers


[www]
        comment = websites
        path = /var/www
        valid users = chris
        read only = No
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you access the server by ipaddress or by its mdns hostname ... \\192.168.0.100\www or \\ubuntu-host-name.local\www

Comment: Have you opened up the samba ports in your firewall?

`sudo ufw allow samba`

Comment: Thanks for the two suggestions. Sadly neither improve the situation. I still see the server in Windows Explorer but when clicking on it to get the shared folders get the message that Windows cannot access the server.

Comment: I have made some progress this morning and now have a big clue as to the problem. I mapped the a network drive on Windows 10 to the share (\\192.168.x.y\folder_name) and selected "use different network credentials" - this enabled me to access the Ubuntu 18.04 server. I have used all the same user names and credentials as the 16.04 server but something is different when accessing the 18.04 server. I will investigate further and see what I can find - but at least I have something working now and think I know where to investigate.

Comment: Did you create a samba user on your 18.04 server? With `smbpasswd -a <user>`?

Comment: Good suggestion but alas yes a samba user was added on the 18.04 server. Currently the workaround seems to be to map to a network and select  "use different network credentials" (as described above). Once completed I can browse the shared files on the 18.04 server from Windows 10 as needed.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue accessing a Samba 4.7.6 share on Ubuntu 18.04 from a VMware on that computer running Windows 10. 
I didn't find a solution, but I found a workaround. I actually can connect to the share if I enter the IP address manually, while going via the Windows explorer computer name doesn't work. It doesn't even show the option to connect with a different user.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.
Solved like this:

vi /etc/samba/smb.conf

```
[global]
(...)
ntlm auth=true
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with these settings too

```
[data]
    path = /data
    browsable = yes
    available = yes
    read only = no
    public = yes
    writable = yes
    guest ok = yes
    create mask = 777
    directory mask = 777
    force create mode = 777
    force directory mode = 777
```